# Emgu VideoWriter saves odd-dimensioned video as even-dimensioned

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm using Emgu.CV in several C# project to save video files. This works fine in most circumstances.

But then I saved a video with dimensions 431 x 359 (odd dimensions). I'm converting each frame to an `Image<Bgr,byte>` object and then saving it using

```
VW?.Write(img.Mat);
```

I have checked that this `Mat` object also has dimensions 431 x 359. But the saved file dimensions are 430 x 358. There appears to be a black line through the right-most pixels in the saved video. This is the code where I initialize the Emgu VideoWriter, and I have checked that the `size` also has dimensions 431 x 359:

```
int codec = Emgu.CV.VideoWriter.Fourcc('X', 'V', 'I', 'D');
VW = new Emgu.CV.VideoWriter(filename, codec, fps, size, true); //XVID-codec
```

I'm using Emgu.CV version 4.5.1.4349.

It's not a problem, but I'm interested to know if anyone knows why this happens. I can't find any documentation describing this behavior.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroblock